# Noncommutative Hilbert basis theorem is false?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

How can I show that for a field $K$, in the free algebra on $2$ generators $K\langle x,y\rangle$, the two-sided ideal $$\big\langle\!\big\langle xy^ix\;\big|\;i\in\mathbb{N}\big\rangle\!\big\rangle =\bigg\{\sum_{i}g_ixy^ixh_i \;\bigg|\; i\in\mathbb{N},\, g_i,h_i\in K\langle x,y\rangle\bigg\}$$ is not generated by any finitely many $f_1,\ldots,f_k\!\in\!K\langle x,y\rangle$, if this is even true?

If not, what other generators of the ideal must I take?

Is there a simpler set of generators of an ideal that is not finitely generated?

Comment: LaTeX tip: The `\in` command already comes with spacing, if you put your own in it will be confused and look bad.

Comment: Yeah, I have a constant struggle with LaTeX's spacing, cause the spacing around `\in` seems too large to me. Now, $\mathbb{N}$ and $g_i$ are closer than $\in$ and $\mathbb{N}$, which is wrong...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $I$ be the two sided ideal generated by $xy^ix$ for all $i \in \mathbb N$ and let $I_n$ be the ideal generated by $xy^ix$ with $i < n$.

First prove that $I_n$ does not contain $xy^nx$.  Do this by arguing that every monomial contained in every polynomial of this ideal contains a string of the form $xy^ix$ with $i < n$ whereas $xy^nx$ does not.  This gives $I_n \neq I$ for all $n$.

Next argue that if there was a finite set of generators for the ideal $I$ then we would have $I = I_n$ for some $n$.  Do this by observing that for each of the generators $f$ we must have $f = \sum_ig_ixy^{a_i}xh_i$ where the sum is over only *finitely many* terms.  Hence taking $n$ large enough we must eventually generate $f$.

Comment: Great, thanks! Regards.