# Are finitely generated subrings of $\mathbb{H}$ Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quaternions, noncommutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $R$ be a finitely generated subring of the ring of real quaternions $\mathbb{H}$, that is, $R$ is the subring generated by a finite subset of $\mathbb{H}$. I want to show (or find a counterexample) that $R$ is Noetherian.

My attempt is the same as the attempt in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222487/is-it-true-that-any-finitely-generated-ring-has-no-infinite-minimal-generating-s). However, this attempt is not correct for general rings as pointed out in the answers. I wonder if there is some special property of $\mathbb{H}$ that would make this attempt work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but maybe you can embed $\mathbb Z\langle X, Y \rangle$ in $\mathbb H$ by sending $X$ and $Y$ to something like $i + \pi j$ and $i + e j$ with $\pi, e$ algebraically independent (so that hopefully that map is injective). And then it would follow from this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317564/noncommutative-hilbert-basis-theorem-is-false

Comment: In fact, it suffices to show that for each $p\in \mathbb{Z}\langle X,Y\rangle$, there exists *some* $a,b\in\mathbb{H}$ such that $p(a,b)\neq 0$.  Then the set of such $(a,b)$ will be an open dense subset of $\mathbb{H}^2$ for each fixed $p$, and so by the Baire category theorem you can find a single pair $(a,b)$ that works for every $p$ simultaneously.

Comment: @Bart Michels: It is known that $\pi$ and $e^\pi$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ and so over $\mathbb{Z}$ also. Isn't it immediate that $$\mathbb{Z}[\pi i,e^\pi j]\cong \mathbb{Z}\langle X,Y\rangle?$$ Here, $\mathbb{Z}[\pi i,e^\pi j]$ is the subring of $\mathbb{H}$ generated by $\{1,\pi i, e^\pi j\}$.

Comment: @morphy22: No.  For instance, note that $(\pi i)^2$ and $(e^\pi j)^2$ commute, but $X^2$ and $Y^2$ do not commute in $\mathbb{Z}\langle X,Y\rangle$.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: I computed for $[a,[b,[a,b]]]$ and I got $-a^2b^2+2(ab)^2-2(ba)^2+b^2a^2$. Then  $[a,[b,[a,b]]]=0$ if and only if $a^2b^2-2(ab)^2=b^2a^2-2(ba)^2$. How can I show this in an 'easy' way? I tried using the form $a+bi+cj+dk$ and also the 2x2 complex matrix form but I don't get the desired result. Maybe I am having some arithmetic errors but It's hard to check because there are too many terms.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Take $a=1+i+j+k$ and $b=1+i+j-k$. Then $[a,[b,[a,b]]]=16i-16j$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was wrong about $[a,[b,[a,b]]]$.  One thing that is always true though is that $[a,b]^2$ always commutes with everything, since commutators have no real part.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ be algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, let $x=a+bi$ and let $y=c+dj$.  Then the subring $R\subset\mathbb{H}$ generated by $x$ and $y$ is not Noetherian.

To prove this, consider the left ideal $I\subseteq R$ generated by the elements $xy^n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  I claim that for each $n$, $xy^n$ is not in the left ideal generated by the $xy^m$ for $m<n$, and so $I$ cannot be finitely generated.

Note first that $R$ is a subring of the quaternion algebra $S$ over the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[a,b,c,d]$.  We may consider $\mathbb{Z}[a,b,c,d]$ as a bigraded ring where the first degree is respect to $a$ and $b$ and the second degree is with respect to $c$ and $d$.  This then makes $S$ a bigraded ring, with $x$ being homogeneous of bidegree $(1,0)$ and $y$ being homogeneous of bidegree $(0,1)$.  Since $x$ and $y$ are homogeneous, the ring $R$ is bigraded as well.

Now suppose we could write $xy^n$ as an $R$-linear combination of the $xy^m$ for $m<n$.  The only way to take a multiple of $xy^m$ that has the same bidegree as $xy^n$ is to take an integer multiple of $y^{n-m}xy^m$, so this in fact means that we can write $$xy^n=\sum_{m<n}k_my^{n-m}xy^m$$ where each $k_m$ is an integer.  Now consider the homomorphism $S\to\mathbb{H}$ given by mapping $a$ to $0$, $b$ to $1$, $c$ to $1$, and $d$ to $2$ (and $i,j,k$ to themselves).  This turns the equation above into $$i(1+2j)^n=\sum_{m<n}k_m(1+2j)^{n-m}i(1+2j)^m.$$  Multiplying both sides by $-i$ and noting that $-i(u+vj)i=u-vj$, we get $$(1+2j)^n=\sum_{m<n}k_m(1-2j)^{n-m}(1+2j)^m.$$  But this now violates unique factorization in the Gaussian integer ring $\mathbb{Z}[j]$, since the right-hand side is divisible by $1-2j$ and the left-hand side is not.

Comment: Thank you. In this case, can we still not show that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]\cong \mathbb{Z}\langle X,Y\rangle$?

Comment: @morphy22 If true, they are not isomorphic under $X \mapsto x, Y \mapsto y$, because (as Eric Wofsey's comment says) $[x, [y, [x, y]]] = 0$.